# Division operation in `u128` results false value

Tags: rust, balances, math

In my node, `Balance` type is `u128`. I have following variable

```rust
let per_block = 100_000_000_000_000_000_u128;
let total = 50_000_000_000_000_000_000_000_u128;
let ratio = per_block.checked_div(total);

assert!(ratio.is_some());
let user_a = 10_000_000_000_000_000_000_000_u128 * ratio;
```

But ratio is `0` even in above case. How do I perform such calculation to get `user_a` finally?

Playground: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=3d556bfb809632b885bf008680dfec8e

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [`per_things`](https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/master/sp_arithmetic/per_things/index.html).

You could use `Perquintill` here:

```rust
use sp_runtime::Perquintill;

let ratio = Perquintill::from_rational(per_block, total);
let user_a = 10_000_000_000_000_000_000_000_u128 * ratio;
```